# How to change this code to another using openfiledailog

Tags: c#, image

I want to take image from openfiledialog and use it in my program
I want to change this code and take image from openfiledialog ,what I must do?

```
string pathToImage = @"test1.gif";

pathToImage = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + pathToImage;

//Try extracting the frames
frames = EnumerateFrames(pathToImage);
if (frames == null || frames.Count() == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code it will give you the path of the image

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

DialogResult dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    this.pathToImage  = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(openFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Comment: why do you need " System.IO.Path.GetFullPath" ? openFileDialog.FileName would give entire path . Also, you need to include Filters in your example to filter images